# How to skip tests containing certain text in their docstring?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I would like to store hints inside each test method's docstring, so the testloader can include or exclude the test based on those hints. Something like this:

```
def test_login_with_valid_credentials(self):
    '''#functional #security #nondestructive'''
    # code goes here
```

Then the testloader would discover all tests containing the substring '#functional' or whatever.

I'm trying to avoid using decorators for this purpose, because I think using docstrings would be more flexible. (Maybe I'm wrong.)

Being new to nose, I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: decorators would be perfect for that, in my opinion. using `@unittest.skipIf` or `skipUnless` with a well-thought condition should do the trick.

Comment: I haven't seen any usage examples of skipIf that would work the way I want. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, this is the actual syntax:

```
@attr(functional=True, security=True, nondestructive=False)
```

And the tests are invoked thusly:

```
/usr/local/bin/nosetests -v --exe -a functional -w test_directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the `@attr` nose decorator just meant for that? https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr(tags=['b','c'])
def test_bc():
    print 1

@attr(tags=['a','b'])
def test_ab():
    print 1

@attr(tags=['a'])
def test_a():
    print 1
```

and then you can select one or several values to run:

```
> nosetests -v -a tags=b  test.py         
test.test_bc ... ok
test.test_ab ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

> nosetests -v -a tags=b -a tags=a test.py
test.test_bc ... ok
test.test_ab ... ok
test.test_a ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.002s
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of typing for what I want to do.

Comment: Also, I would like to keep the tags (attributes) inside the test methods themselves, not in the enclosing module.

Comment: `@attr('functional')` instead of `'''#functional'''` is a lot of typing? You also have to consider this is existing behavior, given for free, instead of having to roll your own implementation if you want to use the docstring (note that you would also be using docstrings for something they are not intended for). And the decorators are attached to the methods, not the module, even though they are above the method and not inside.

Comment: Like I said, seems like a lot of typing for what I'm trying to accomplish. If I want to add N attributes to a method, that means N @attr() calls, right?

Comment: Attribute values can be lists, see the example I added. It doubt it can get better in terms of verbosity, but I still thinks it's a better way to go than the docstring parsing.

Comment: That looks promising, then. Thanks.